# uniform space between bar in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
ax3.bar(D, HighC_21, facecolor='g', width=0.8, alpha=1.0, align='edge')  
ax3.bar(D, LowC_21, bottom=HighC_21, color='r', width=0.8, alpha=1, align='edge')
```

I am using this code to plot bar on x-axis but there is uneven space at start and end. How can I make bar spread evenly on x-axis?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the first input to [`pyplot.bar`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar) to specify the x positions of each bar. You are currently using the value `D` so a bar should appear at each x position in `D`. Based on your question, the values in `D` are not where you want the bars to be.

You would need to change the first input to be the (evenly spaced) values that you want. You could easily do this with [`numpy.linspace`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html).

```
import numpy as np

# Specify where you want the first and last bars as minX and maxX
x = np.linspace(minX, maxX, len(LowC_21))
ax3.bar(x, HighC_21, facecolor='g', width=0.8, alpha=1.0)  
ax3.bar(x, LowC_21, bottom=HighC_21, color='r', width=0.8, alpha=1)
```